# Having troube to mount my FILES partition

Tags: mount

this is the error im getting

```
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/ubuntu/FILES: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999" "/dev/sda5" "/media/ubuntu/FILES"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Btw, I'm having trouble format my pc lately I'm getting an error from windows installer when i try to format the windows partition, this one I'm trying to access it's vital to me, cause everything I have is there... it maybe a problem with my HD? Tnx!

EDIT: just did this to try to fix it but now i cant even see it here anymore

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda5
Mounting volume... $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 0...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 1...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 2...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 3...OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Failed to access '/dev/sda5': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sda5': No such file or directory
Remount failed: No such file or directory*
```

TNX!

Comment: Since it is in NTFS, I strongly suggest to you that you access your Windows installation and control it from there.

Comment: Most often caused by Windows fast start up or its always on hibernation. Or you just have Windows hibernation on. check that is off. And if it needs chkdsk then you can only do that from Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - BACKUP your USB drive.

Any command (like I am about to share) - possibly will corrupt/loose your data. So PLEASE bask the device up.

Assuming that you have BACKED it up

```
ntfsfix /dev/hda5
```

This is assuming that you have installed **ntfs-3g** so you refer to that device.

I can see you tried the command I mentioned - but the Error messages do not help....

To show which drive is mounted do a

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

And assuming that your USB Drive is there... change the **ntfsfix**